# Employer Missing My Yearly Review - How To React?

Tags: salary, employer-relations, performance-reviews, employer

My employer has, for almost 5 months, missed out on my yearly review which was due last November. As a small company we are all extremely busy, however I find it hard to believe they can't spare 20 minutes to go over my performance and discuss salary.

I am not alone in this. Many of my colleagues have had to wait months before their reviews, but at least they had them!

I've already politely enquired many times to my employer about setting a date for the review. I've either had the date set which has then been pushed back indefinitely, or promises of "it will definitely be this week" broken.

I love my job, but the potential loss of earnings is making me seriously consider moving on. However, I'd much prefer to stay.

How should I go about getting my yearly review, or am I wasting my time?

I am based in the UK if that makes a difference.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**

Unhappy with the way in which the company was treating me, I looked elsewhere for a new job. I accepted a new position at a different company. Not only is it for a higher salary, it was also a step up/promotion!

Thank you all for your input.

Comment: "*I've already politely enquired many times to my employer about setting a date for the review.*" Have you tried being more direct or less-than-polite? You're basically asking "how can I set up a meeting with my manager?" which is tricky for us to answer since we don't know your situation.

Comment: Others have had their annual review but you haven't, I get that bit. What I don't understand is whether or not your colleagues chased up their bosses to have an annual review, have you asked them if they did? How likely is it that this is simply a case of a lack of time? Could it also be the case that the company does not want to invest in you anymore? Does the company know your position when it comes to how much you are paid? What kind of work do you do as that is another factor in how this will play out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are 100% correct that delaying the review is saving the company money, money that you won't ever see because you didn't get the raise earlier. There's little chance of being back-paid to the date you should have had your review, unless your employment contract states there will be a yearly review.

Be proactive.

Most places use a meeting booking system (like Outlook) that let's *you* book a meeting with your manager.

If that's the case, book a 30 minute meeting with the title of "Yearly review".

If it's not the case, ask the manager what time this week you can have your yearly review.

Either way, it's false that he doesn't have time for a review - **it's his job to review his subordinates**. If he's not reviewing, he is not doing his job. So he needs to make time.

Make no mistake, your company is deliberately delaying this. You should look elsewhere to find a company that, unlike yours, values its employees.

Comment: +1 for saying it's the employers responsibility to review subordinates

Comment: What @JavaGuru said.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you'll get yours eventually, if others have done so.

So, just keep trying and you'll get there.

I've pretty much assumed that the only way to get a measurable salary increase is to move jobs - I don't remember the last time I got a review based salary increase.

Comment: I generally get a salary increase that is marginally above that years increase in cost of living, but never substantially more.  It's axiomatic, particular in the software industry where I work, that moving jobs is how you increase salary.

Comment: Also companies tend to put this off to save them selves some money. Last place I worked at did that to me then I found out that the new employees straight out of uni were getting the same as me. Got another job and a 75% increase. When it gets to this stage it's a good idea to cut bait and find somewhere else.

Comment: @Snowlockk - That's a point.  It might also be the case that the company doesn't really place much importance on the review process, especially if they're broadly happy with how their employees are working.

Comment: @Pete problem is this is the process that normally causes salary increases to happen. If they don't do it then there is no increase. Never heard of a company willing to back date. So the employee loses out.